# Appium+android current activity & awaiting activity

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, appium

Using Appium (for android on windows), I need to check the login scenario, after entering the user & password, click on the sign in button , the new (awaiting)activity is opened, 
1. Please guide me how can i get the current activity, that is before the sign in button is pressed.
2. how to navigate to the awaiting activity, after the sign in button is pressed, so as to check the success on login.

Answer (score 1):

You have `driver.currentActivity();` for knowing current activity where you are,
and `driver.startActivity(appPackage,appActivity);` to switch from one activity to another, or you can open a new app with new activity.

Once try it,may help you.